# The use of upper case

Tags: sociolinguistics

Can the use of upper case be considered a graphological feature? And therefore be suitable for inclusion in an analysis? A newspaper article has to be analysed. In its first sentence, it presents some words (not all) in upper case. This is unusual and clearly done for effect. But I'd like to be sure that this is classed as a graphological feature. I haven't seen upper case mentioned in any description of linguistic graphology, even though I expected it to be included as a visual/physical feature.(Because in graphology the way a text appears is significant.)

Comment: Any question of the type "can X be considered/classed as a Y feature" is going to depend on your choice of analytical framework.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Just like any change in sound can be called phonetic, any change in written form can be called graphemic.

The real question is whether it's *useful* to analyze it that way. And that really depends on the rest of your analysis, and on the framework you're building from. Sure, uppercase and lowercase absolutely differ, and there are absolutely reasons people use one instead of the other—so what does that say about the specific corpus you're looking at? Can you draw interesting and meaningful conclusions from it?

Personally, I'd say yes, you certainly can analyze the use of upper case for emphasis; you could even use eye-tracking equipment to measure concretely how much it draws people's attention, or time people's reading to see if it affects comprehension time. All of this would fall under the umbrella of graphemics.

P.S. Do people still call this "graphology"? I'm used to it being called "graphemics", because the word "graphology" got co-opted by the pseudoscientists who say you can psychoanalyze someone from a handwriting sample. I'm assuming you're *not* interested in that, and are instead talking about the linguistic analysis of orthographies and writing systems.